# Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Suppose that in a population the probability of survival of an individual would survive is 99/100. If 5 people in the population were to buy an insurance,
Using Poisson distribution what is the probability that exactly 2 of such person in the population would die

Thought: $X=$ number of people dying
$$\begin{align}
X & \sim \mathcal{Pois} (1/100 \cdot 5)
\\[2ex] \mathsf P (X = 2) & = \frac{[0.05^2 \cdot e^{-0.05}] }2
\end{align}$$
Am I right? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the distribution of the count of successes in $n=5$ trials, where each trial has an independent and identical rate of success ($p=1/100$).

This is a Binomial Distribution.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=2) & = \dbinom{5}{2} \dfrac {99^3}{100^5}
\\ & \approx {0.00097}
\end{align}$$

---

The Poison Approximation to Binomial is not really accurate at such a small sample size.  But if you must use it, then indeed:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=2) &\;\dot\approx\; \frac{0.05^2\cdot\mathsf e^{-0.05}}{2!}
\\ & \approx 0.00119
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, i thought of binomial distribution. But I was told to use the law of rare event to evaluate this question. Hence I used poisson distribution Thanks.

Comment: Therefore if i were to use poisson distribution I can't use X~Pois (1/100) right? Since this is the "average" for 1 person?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubts!

Comment: @LimZhiJian Well, if you must use it... then it is: $X\dot\sim \mathcal{Pois}(np)$